# Code runs on local Julia but breaks on computer cluster when adding RCall package

Tags: curl, package, julia, rcall

I have a code that runs well on local julia but fails when I try running them on a cluster. It breaks when I do `Pkg.add(“RCall”)`. Before I run Julia I have already loaded module `Julia/1.8.2` and `R/4.2.1-foss-2022a`. Then I `cd` to where my julia project is and execute the code.

The error message is

```
┌ Error: curl_easy_setopt: 48

└ @ Downloads.Curl /cache/build/default-amdci4-6/julialang/julia-release-1-dot-8/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:29

┌ Error: curl_easy_setopt: 48

└ @ Downloads.Curl /cache/build/default-amdci4-6/julialang/julia-release-1-dot-8/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:29

┌ Error: curl_easy_setopt: 48

└ @ Downloads.Curl /cache/build/default-amdci4-6/julialang/julia-release-1-dot-8/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:29
```

By the way, Julia exit by itself after shows the above error message and then this message shown in the terminal:
`Segmentation fault`.

An update: then I try to load R after I cd to the julia project, this time RCall runs successfully but I still get `curl_easy_setopt:48` as shown above. Although the package works fine now but I don't understand the error message.

Can anyone help me understand what happened and how to fix it?

Kind regards,

Hongyu.

Comment: Error 48: An option passed to libcurl is not recognized/known. Refer to the appropriate documentation. This is most likely a problem in the program that uses libcurl. The error buffer might contain more specific information about which exact option it concerns. Source: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html  You should include your curl code.